# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have a strange problem. I'm running a rails server local, everything works great. But when I tried to clone the rails server in a cloud server (amazon aws), one controller don't work.

I'm kind of newbie in rails, but I can't realize whats going on. I have some other entities working, but this one doesnt.

when I try to get /ingressos:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/bilheteria_mobile_server/app/views/ingressos/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #14):

11:     <th></th>
12:   </tr>
13: 
14: <% @ingressos.each do |ingresso| %>
15:   <tr>
16:     <td><%= ingresso.usuario.nome %></td>
17:     <td><%= ingresso.conteudo.titulo %></td>
Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/bilheteria_mobile_server
```

I know that my Ingresso is getting nil, but what this can be? If in my local server I can run everything?

Anyone can give me a hint? Thanks!

edit:

For NO reason it become to works! Ok, the error has changed, it appears:

Erro loading Base64 when I use: require 'Base64'. But I need this to do somethings later, on create. How can I load Base64? Has any diference that my cloud server is a linux machine and my local server is on a mac?

thx!

Comment: If this was just a standard Rails question, I would say to check the Controller's `index` definition to make sure you defined `@ingressos = Ingressos.all`. It's worth checking anyway, but if it's working in the local server I'm not so sure this is the problem.

Comment: Can you check the cloud database to see that the table linked to Ingressos has valid records? Perhaps you have Ingressos records in the local database but not the remote.

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks for all the hints, can you help me with this new issue?

Comment: Guys, i figured what was the problem. I have no idea why the error change from that in question to the base64, but when I use require 'Base64' in my local machine, it works, but in the cloud machine I need to change to require 'base64', with lowercase. Don't know why :p

Comment: is your local machine a PC w/windows?  My guess is teh reason it works is your local machine uses a case-insenstive file system, whereas the ubuntu vm you are running on uses a case-sensitive file system

Comment: sorry missed the part of you being on a mac,  but mac is base insensitive file system as well.  so just use `require "base64"` everywhere and you will be fine (as that is the correct library name)

Comment: Yeah, I changed in my local server too and works. Just in case I'll do this forever from now on xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, changing require "Base64" to require "base64" has solved my problem. The first error disappeared, which is weird, but I'll not complain about this. Thanks to the guys who tried to resolve the issue with me in the comment session. cya